# CSS to LESS Syntax

Tags: css, syntax, less

I have this code, that has selectors of different types, I was wondering how this code would be if it where in LESS:

```
ul.sidebar-menu li a.active, 
ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover, 
ul.sidebar-menu li a:focus {
    color: #1FB5AD;
    display: block;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover, 
ul.sidebar-menu li a:focus {
    padding-left:30px;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a { 
    font-size:1.1em; 
    padding:8px 0 8px 25px; 
    color: #888 
}

ul.sidebar-menu { 
    margin-top: 10px
}
```

I already do that, but I`m not sure if is the best way.
Anyone can provide a theoretical response?

Comment: [Can you show what you've actually tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code written for less:

```
ul.sidebar-menu li a.active, 
ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover, 
ul.sidebar-menu li a:focus {
    color: #1FB5AD;
    display: block;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover, 
ul.sidebar-menu li a:focus {
    padding-left:30px;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a { 
    font-size:1.1em; 
    padding:8px 0 8px 25px; 
    color: #888 
}

ul.sidebar-menu { 
    margin-top: 10px
}
```

If it looks remarkably similar to what you posted, it's because I didn't change anything.

If you want it rewritten in a way that involves nesting, then you ought to consider how you want to organize the LESS code.

Personally, I'd rewrite all the code to use classes, because you're increasing the specificity of your selectors for no good reason. leaving the `ul` and `li` selectors in there is just going to make things more difficult later when you want to change the structure at all.

But to nest the code that was written, you could use:

```
ul.sidebar-menu {
    li {
         a {
             &.active,
             &:hover,
             &:focus {
                 color: #1FB5AD;
                 display: block;
             }

             &:hover,
             &:focus {
                 padding-left: 30px;
             }

             color: #888;
             font-size:1.1em; 
             padding:8px 0 8px 25px; 
         }
    }

    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I think you can just connect the li and a... I guess it doesn't make too much difference since there is nothing else under the li

Comment: @Huangism, while that's true, it would prove to be a poor choice when you eventually need to style the `li` element. Either way the structure is a poor choice, as you should avoid more than one level of nesting, and including unnecessary selectors. It would be better to remove the `li` selector completely, but as I said in my answer, I'd use classes and keep the specificity of all the selectors at `0-0-1-0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a website like: http://css2less.cc/ to check this.

```
ul.sidebar-menu li a.active,ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover,ul.sidebar-menu li a:focus {
    color: #1FB5AD;
    display: block;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover,ul.sidebar-menu li a:focus {
    padding-left:30px;
}
ul.sidebar-menu {
    margin-top: 10px;
    li {
        a {
            font-size:1.1em;
            padding:8px 0 8px 25px;
            color: #888;
        }
    }
}
```